# Sum of values larger than average per column in multiple matrices

Tags: bash, awk

I have some matrix in files given as parameters. I need to find the average of each column and sum only the numbers in column that are bigger or equal to the column average.

For example:

`f1:`

```
10 20 30
5  8
9
```

`f2`:

```
1 1 2 2 3
5
6   6
1 1 1 1 1
```

`f3`:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 4 10
8
10 9 8 7 6
```

and the output should be

```
f1: 19 20 30
f2: 11 6 2 2 3
f3: 18 16 16 7 10
```

You run the program like this:

```
MS.1 f1 f2 f3
```

So far I got this:

```awk
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    M=0
    M1=0
    counter=1
    fname=ARGV[1]
    printf fname":"
}

(fname==FILENAME) {
    split($0,A," ")
    for(i=1;i<=length(A);i++) {
        B[i]=B[i]+A[i]
        if(A[i]<=0||A[i]>=0)
            C[i]=C[i]+1
    }
    for(i=1;i<=length(B);i++) {
        if((C[i]<0||C[i]>0))
            D[i]=B[i]/C[i]
    }
    for(i=1;i<=length(A);i++) {
        if(A[i]>=D[i])
            E[i]=E[i]+" "+A[i]
    }
}

(fname!=FILENAME) {
    for(i=1;i<=length(E);i++) {
        printf " "E[i]
    }
    printf "\n"
    for(i=1;i<=length(B);i++) {
        B[i]=0
    }
    for(i=1;i<=length(C);i++) {
        C[i]=0
    }
    fname=FILENAME
    printf fname":"
}

END {
    for(i=1;i<=length(B);i++) {
        printf " "B[i]
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```

but it only works for the first file and then it messes up.

My output is

```
f1: 19 20 30
f2: 30 26 31 1 1 1
f3: 24 16 16 11 16 0
```

I know I got a problem with all the array things.

Comment: Please format input and output

Comment: If you're using gnu awk (gawk), `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` should be useful to you https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html

Comment: is input data Fixed-Width Data separate? or single space separate?

Comment: for example `f1` and `f2` have 3 and 2 (respectively) characters as Fixed-Width, and `f3` has a single space separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `gawk`, assuming default blanks separator for `awk` (`6   6` has two columns, for example)

```
cat script.awk

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i){
        d[FILENAME][FNR][i] = $i
        sum[FILENAME][i] += $i
        ++rows[FILENAME][i]
    }
    if(NF>cols[FILENAME]) cols[FILENAME]=NF
    ++rows_total[FILENAME]
}
END{
    for(fname in rows_total){
        printf "%s:", fname
        for(c=1; c<=cols[fname]; ++c){
            avg = sum[fname][c] / rows[fname][c]
            sumtmp = 0
            for(r=1; r<=rows_total[fname]; ++r){
                if(d[fname][r][c] >= avg) sumtmp+=d[fname][r][c]
            }
            printf " %d", sumtmp
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}

awk -f script.awk f1 f2 f3
```

you get,

```
f1: 19 20 30
f2: 11 6 2 2 3
f3: 18 16 16 7 10
```

Answer (score 1):

here the combination of `bash` and `awk` will simplify the script

save this as `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $@; do
   awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {a[i]=$i; sum[i]+=$i; c[i]++}; next}
                {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(c[i] && $i>=sum[i]/c[i]) csum[i]+=$i}
        END     {printf "%s", FILENAME; 
                 for(i=1;i<=length(csum);i++) printf "%s", OFS csum[i];
                 print ""}' "$f"{,}
done;
```

and run with

```
$ ./script.sh f1 f2 f3
```